# Error sdk android en flutter al instalar

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Amigos estoy instalando flutter en mi pc, tengo todo configurado correctamente pero al ejecutar el flutter doctor me arroja el siguiente error en el sdk
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya he modificado el ANDROID_HOME y nada, includo con el comando

`flutter config --android-sdk C:\Android\Android_SDK\`

Y me sigue generando el mismo error, alguien podría ayudar en como solucionar

Comment: Tienes actualizado el sdk? tienes actualizado tu android studio? instala las extensiones en VS code también si es que lo vas a utilizar ahí.

Answer (score 1):

En Android Studio verifica que tengas correcto tu SDK.
Agregar el PATH a tu variable de entorno, la ruta debe ser la misma que aparece en la captura(Sdk)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Elimina e instala otra vez Android Studio, la instalación es automatica, por lo cual no debes modificar nada. 
También puedes instalar Java JDK(parte de la instalación ).